# How can I cancel certain functions while inheriting?

Tags: java

This is a fairly odd question that someone asked me recently and I couldn't think of a achieve  this.

Let `Person` be a class with several public functions and attributed. Say one of the attributes is color of the eye, with two functions: `getColor()` and `setColor()`.

Now let `Teacher` extend to `Person` to inherit it's properties.

Her question: **What if I don't want to inherit `getColor()` and `setColor()` but the rest of the functions?**

My initial thought was to `@Override` all of them and return void, doing nothing. However, I don't think this is safe or preferred method, maybe there is a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's essentially the definition of the “contract” of Person, by inheriting from Person, Teacher is “promising” to behave in that way.

Aside from refactoring Person to inherit from, say, `interface PersonBase` and `interface PersonWithEyes`, you're kinda stuck with “doing the right thing” in that context, if you want to present a sane implementation of `Person` to your callers.

Comment: Left-field but valid alternative: Drop the OOP model and use an Entity model instead. O:-)

Comment: "Promising" is a good keyword here. I know that it promises it, I was checking if there was absolutely no way of achieving this.

Comment: In this, specific, case, one might also define a value of `COLOUR_UNKNOWN`, make it the default, and run with that. (I shoehorned some things in like that due to the US COPPA laws to handle underage videogame players, at one point.)

Answer (score 2):

That's bad.  The whole point of inheritance is that all implementations of some interface (or subclasses of some class) have the same contract.

You would need to define a new interface.  You might also consider shifting the whole design upside down such that the class without the methods is the superclass.

Answer (score 1):

You can either make them private to the parent class, or override them. Making them private, of course, makes them useless outside of the parent class as well.

Another option is to use composition and delegation, and just don't pass on those methods--but you lose the is-a relationship unless you have very granular interfaces.

Comment: Yes, private wouldn't be an option, obviously. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for cannot be done in a "moral" sense so to speak: anything that you do to achieve this is something you shouldn't do.  Why?  Because **subtypes are supposed to be usable everywhere their supertype is**.  This is called the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Think about it this way: when you define the `Person` class and specify that it has a `getColor()` and `setColor()` method, basically you are making a promise all of your class' users that if they have a `Person` reference, they can invoke methods with those names on it.  And when you subclass `Person` to make the `Teacher` class, **you are inheriting the same promise**; somebody may refer to one of your `Teacher` objects through a `Person` reference, and thus you are bound to respect all the promises that the superclass makes.

You may also want to read about the [Circle-ellipse Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem) while you're at it—it's intimately related to what you're asking about.

Comment: It is very much so.  In the Circle-Ellipse Problem, if you try to make Circle a subtype of Ellipse, then the problem you have is that Ellipse supports operations that make no sense for a Circle.  This is comparable to making Teacher a subtype of Person, and then running into the issue that Person has operations that don't make sense for Teacher.

Comment: But a `Teacher` does have eyes, so the base-class properties are meaningful.  This is not the case for `Circle` vs. `Ellipse`.

Comment: The fact that the original poster wants to have `Teacher` **not** support some of the operations that `Person` does is, taken at face value (as I am taking it), evidence enough that those supertype operations would not make sense for the subtype.

Comment: And an extra comment on your "`Teacher` does have eyes" remark: this is precisely the kind of thinking that leads to the Circle-Ellipse problem.  You think of classes and objects as models of real world things, and you conclude that, because a teacher is-a type of person, that `Teacher` should be a subtype of `Person`.  The Circle-Ellipse problem, however, shows that this reasoning is wrong; what matters is the **operations** that the types support and their **contracts**.  A real-life circle is an ellipse, but a textbook `Ellipse` object supports operations that a `Circle` object doesn't.

Comment: @sacundium: If you can think of a situation where it would lead to a logical absurdity for a `Teacher` to inherit these properties/methods from `Person`, then I'll agree with you.  Until then, I don't see this as a Circle-Ellipse problem (it sounds more like the OP just doesn't *want* the `Teacher` to expose these properties).

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't make sense.

Consider that you could always do this:

```
class Person {
    public int getColor() { ... }
    public void setColor(int x) { ... }
}

class Teacher extends Person {}

...

Person p = new Teacher();  // Create a Teacher
p.setColor(5);             // But access it as if it were a Person
```

What would it mean to "prevent inheritance"?

You could always do something like

```
class Teacher {
    private Person person = new Person();
}
```

i.e. a "has-a" relationship rather than an "is-a" relationship.  But that doesn't make much sense either.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use inheritance.

Break up your hierarchy so you have a base class with all the methods you do want to inherit, and then add the ones you don't in a descendant.

After that elegance, is a big fat bloke with a beard claiming to be Kierra Knightly...

Override and throw a NotImplementedException, with big comments all over the code, that say REFACTOR, at a push.